# Adobe air Native Process only works in the flash environment, but when deployed i get Error #3219

Tags: actionscript, process, air, desktop, native

I've been trying to use ffmpeg with an air app that I made in flash cs5.5. I have it so that ffmpeg.exe needs to be located in the directory where the air app is installed (File.applicationDirectory.nativePath).

For some reason this only works when I run the program through the flash dev environment. But when I actually deploy the app, I get error #3219:The NativeProcess could not be started. ffmpeg.exe is located in the same folder.

I actually don't know the full message that it gives...not sure what the property of the error that will give me that message when I catch it. All I know is that it's error 3219.

Would this be a profile issue? If i didn't have the extended desktop desktop profile, I don't think I would be able to get this error, I'd get a profiling error wouldn't I?

I've disabled user access control as well...I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

So I'm the OP, and I just realized that you can't use native process calls if you do not install the air application through the exe installer, which is an option in publish settings. I've been using the air installer.

Comment: been really bangin my head against this one, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

one thing to mention is that (I'm sure you already know) the NativeProcess works only on that OS where it was compiled, so if you compile on a windows box your NativeProcess will only work on windows and not on unix/mac.

I don't know how you call the native process, but here is a code snippet that I extracted of one of my working Classes, maybe comparing it with your aproach it will give you some hint to find the problem :)

```
        import flash.desktop.*;
        import flash.errors.*;
        import flash.events.*;
        import flash.filesystem.*;

        public function execute():void
    {
                    var executablePath:String = "C:\ffmpeg.exe";
                    var parametersString:String = "-i input.avi -b 64k output.avi";

        if(NativeProcess.isSupported) {

            var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
                var file:File = new File(String(executablePath));
            var parameters:Array;
            parameters = parametersString.split(" ");
            for each ( var parameter:String in parameters ) {
                    args.push(parameter);
            }
        }

        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;

        startExecution(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    }

    private function startExecution(nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo):void
    {
        var nativeProcess:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
                nativeProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExitError);
            var msg:String = "";

                try {
                    nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
                    trace("Trying to start process");
                } catch (error:IllegalOperationError) {
                    trace("Illegal Operation: "+error.toString());
                } catch (error:ArgumentError) {
                    trace("Argument Error: "+error.toString());
                } catch (error:Error) {
                    trace("Error: "+error.toString());
                }

                if (nativeProcess.running) {
                    trace("Native Process Support");
                }
    }

    public function onExitError(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
    {
        trace("Native Process Exit code: "+event.exitCode);
    }
```